# How to get value of <a> </a> to back end? Python Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

If I had an html code with:

```
<a name="patient_name" href="{{url_for('patient_history')}}">James</a>
```

Is it possible for me to get this value of 'James' via something like

```
request.form['patient_name']?
```

Is there any similar way that the value of James can be passed to the back end?

Comment: Append `?value=James` to the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to submit value to the backend:

1. using `GET`: like [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) has mentioned, you can put it at the `href`:

`<a name="patient_name" href="{{url_for('patient_history')}}/?value=James">James</a>`

2. using `POST`: by using `form` tag and hidden input field:

> ```
> <form action={{url_for('patient_history')}} method="POST">
>   <input type="text" value="James" hidden="hidden" />
>   <button name="patient_name" type="submit">James</button>    
> </form>
> ```

Comment: In the first option, should it not be href"{{url_for('patient_history', value='James')}}" or do both work?

Comment: It depends on the func url_for(), since i dont know what is inside that function, i just use the safest way to generate the result.